# Is there a way to make this shorter and clearer?

Tags: c++, stdmap

Let's say I have this included:

```
#include <map>
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <string>
```

And the code:

```
int main()
{
    typedef std::map< std::string, boost::any > table;
    table foobar;
    foobar["foo"] = table();
    table* foobarfoo = boost::any_cast< table* >( foobar["foo"] );
    (*foobarfoo)["bar"] = int(5);
    int* test = boost::any_cast< int* >( (*foobarfoo)["bar"]);
}
```

This works fine though it doesn't really look good, especially when I need to take the pointer from the `map(int* test here)` in one line.
What I really would love to see here is something like that:

```
int main()
{
    typedef std::map< std::string, boost::any > table;
    table foobar;
    foobar["foo"] = table();
    foobar["foo"]["bar"] = int(5);
    int* test = boost::any_cast< int* >( foobar["foo"]["bar"]);
}
```

This looks much, much clearer, but it won't work that way. My question is, is there a way to make the second code kinda working with some small modifications or is there an alternative that would look as good as the second example and still work?

Comment: "shorter" and "clearer" are mutually exclusive. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can cast `any` object to reference types.

In this case there is ugly double `any_cast` on last line:

```
int main()
{
    typedef std::map< std::string, boost::any > table;
    table foobar;
    foobar["foo"] = table();
    boost::any_cast< table& >( foobar["foo"] )["bar"] = int(5);
    int* test = boost::any_cast< int* >( &(boost::any_cast< table& >( foobar["foo"] )["bar"]));
}
```

You can make it more pretty by saving a reference to resul of first cast:

```
int main()
{
    typedef std::map< std::string, boost::any > table;
    table foobar;
    foobar["foo"] = table();
    table& foo_table = boost::any_cast< table& >( foobar["foo"] );
    foo_table["bar"] = int(5);
    int* test = boost::any_cast< int* >( &(foo_table["bar"]) );
}
```

If this kind of operation is often needed, you can consider changing type of outer map (if nothing, but `table`s will be stored in it) or make a helper function which would look like `int* test = get_value<int>(foobar, "foo", "bar");`